# How to efficiently iterate over a list of objects in julia?

Tags: optimization, julia

I want this code to run as fast as possible. And what is the most efficient way to iterate over a list of objects and change their fields or calculate some variables using them?
Here is my code:

```
mutable struct typeA
    a::Float64
end

mutable struct typeB
    b::Float64
end

mutable struct typeC
    c::Float64
end

types = Union{typeA, typeB, typeC}
function change(n::Int64, list::Array{types, 1})
    for i = 1:n
        j = rand(1:3)
        chosen = list[j]
        u = rand()
        if typeof(chosen) == typeA
            if u < chosen.a
                chosen.a = u
            end
        elseif typeof(chosen) == typeB
            if u < chosen.b
                chosen.b = u
            end
        elseif typeof(chosen) == typeC
            if u > chosen.c
                chosen.c = u
            end
        end
    end
    list
end       

list = Union{types}[typeA(0.7), typeB(0.5), typeC(0.9)]
@time change(10000, list)
```

And here is the results:

> 0.072776 seconds (85.81 k allocations: 4.694 MiB)

And for the second time:

> 0.001378 seconds (4 allocations: 160 bytes)

Answer (score 4):

I understand that you want to speed up the inner loop part (without changing the general logic). If this is the case then change `typeof(chosen) == typeA` to `typeof(chosen) === typeA` or `chosen isa typeA` (the same for `typeB` and `typeC`) in the `if` and `elseif` clauses and you should see around 3x speedup.

Comment: What about the for loop? This code is just an example. I am doing a project which I need to speed up accessing and changing the fields of structures. I need about 10x speedup.

Comment: Loops are fast. You could squeeze out some performance, but if you want to really significantly improve the performance then separately sample how many times you want to run the operation on `list[1]`, `list[2]` and `list[2]` and do them separately, as the major cost you have now that you should try to avoid is `j = rand(1:3)`.

Comment: Why do we get a 3x speedup here? Should we always prefer `===` when it comes to type comparisons?

Comment: Replacing the line  if typeof(chosen) == typeA with  if chosen === typeA  results in around 5x speedup!

Comment: Sorry ! I think I should explain my question differently. What is the best way to declare a function over the fields of different structures in the most efficient way. The code which I posted above is just an example.

Comment: @kdheepak `==` is a generic function that can be extended, whereas `isa` and `===` are much simpler internals that cannot change.  In most cases, there won't be a performance difference and `==` is preferred precisely because it allows customized notions of equality.  But when you're comparing types it's best to use the explicit type predicates (`isa` and `<:`); not only will they be more robust, but you'll also see a performance improvement in cases of type-instability like this.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for multiple dispatch in this example:

```
change!(x::typeA, u) = if u < x.a; x.a = u; end
change!(x::typeB, u) = if u < x.b; x.b = u; end
change!(x::typeC, u) = if u > x.c; x.c = u; end

function change(n, list)
    for i = 1:n
        j = rand(1:3)
        chosen = list[j]
        u = rand()
        change!(chosen, u)
    end
    list
end
```

This gives a slight improvement over the previous answer. Further more I recommend using https://github.com/JuliaCI/BenchmarkTools.jl for benchmarking performance. With `@btime change(10000, $list)` I get

- `615.299 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)` for the original code
- `198.800 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)` after replacing `==` with `===` and
- `193.601 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)` with the multiple dispatch implementation.

Comment: Is it always the fastest way possible? I mean in every code and every function.